# Connection between what-that and it-that as clauses emphasized subject or object in sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

I am in a dilemma about whether the sentences are correct.
Any tips about this would be welcome.

1. What made us upset was that you did not come in time for our meeting.
2. It is you did not come in time for our meeting that made us upset.
3. What we find a good habit is that you came in time for a meeting.
4. It is you come in time for a meeting that we find a good habit.

Comment: (2) and (4) are not correct. After _it is_ you need _the fact that you..._. Also, (2) would be better with _it was_, since the people were made upset in the past.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use "your coming..." after "it is ..." ?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: But, how to emphasize the object compliment.  If "It is to sing that he wants me." is correct ?

Comment: It's grammatical, but not at all idiomatic. We would normally say "He wants me to sing, not to dance".

Comment: Another aspect of emphasizing "It is the task needs to be done today that I want to tell you " Is it correct ?

Comment: _It is the task that needs to be done today that I want to tell you about._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117626/discussion-between-marek-and-kate-bunting).